# Строки в Java. Изменение первого и последнего слова

Tags: java, строки

Есть предложение, например: "Сегодня хороший день для программирования". И в этом предложение нужной найти первое и последнее слово и поменять их местами.

Comment: А что вы пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Я сначала пробегал цыклом до пробела и пытался определить наальное слово потом так же конечно но особо ничего не получалось.

Comment: Если вам был дан правильный ответ, пометьте его галкой напротив - это будет полезно для тех, кто в дальнейшем наткнется на эту тему.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте [`Split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) для разбиения строки на слова (разделителем будет пробел). Затем просто поменяйте в массиве первый и последний элементы и выводите их:

```
String tmp, s = "Сегодня хороший день для программирования";
String[] words = s.split(" ");
tmp = words[0];
words[0] = words[words.length-1];
words[words.length-1] = tmp;
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.print(word + " ");
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/0kVhPT)

Вывод:

> программирования хороший день для Сегодня

---

Если слова будут разделяться не только пробелами, а ещё запятыми или точкой с запятой, например, то используйте регулярные выражения:

```
String[] words = s.split("\\W+");
```

Comment: Спасибо я только начал изучать Java и опыта особо нет .

Comment: Денис , обясни можалуйста вот эту часть 
    words[0] = words[words.length-1];
    words[words.length-1] = tmp;

Comment: @ВладКеся Запоминаем первое слово, запихиваем туда последнее слово, в последнее слово пихаем первое слово, которое запомнили. Обычная перестановка местами 2-х элементов массива.

Answer (score 3):

```
    String str = "Сегодня хороший день для программирования";
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    String temp = words[words.length - 1];
    words[words.length - 1] = words[0];
    words[0] = temp;
    str = Arrays.stream(words).collect(joining(" "));
```

Разбиваем строку на слова. В полученном массиве меняем местами первый и последний элемент, затем объединяем обратно в строку.

Comment: Artem Можешь объяснить вот эту часть кода
String temp = words[words.length - 1];
    words[words.length - 1] = words[0];

Comment: меняем местами элементы

Comment: Смотри мы берём находим последнее слово и записуем его в temp .
Потом говорим что бы последнее слово стало первыйм. А первое послдним вот с помошью этой строчки" words[0] = temp;"